# Traceback using columns in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, traceback

For some reason the following code from a youtube tutorial gives a traceback due to the commented line. He and other successfully ran it in python 3.

```
import Quandl
import pandas as pd
import math

df = Quandl.get("WIKI/GOOGL")
df = df[['Adj. Open',  'Adj. High',  'Adj. Low',  'Adj. Close', 'Adj. Volume']]
df['HL_PCT'] = (df['Adj. High'] - df['Adj. Low']) / df['Adj. Close'] * 100.0
df['PCT_change'] = (df['Adj. Close'] - df['Adj. Open']) / df['Adj. Open'] * 100.0

df = df[['Adj. Close', 'HL_PCT', 'PCT_change', 'Adj. Volume']]

forecast_col = 'Adju. Close'
df.fillna(-99999, inplace=True)

forecast_out = int(math.ceil(0.01*len(df)))

df['label'] = df[forecast_col].shift(-forecast_out) #moves columns out 10% into future
df.dropna(inplace=True)
print(df.head())
```

It gives:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\student\Anaconda2\envs\py35\lib\site-packages\pandas\indexes\ba
se.py", line 1945, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(key)
  File "pandas\index.pyx", line 137, in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas
\index.c:4154)
  File "pandas\index.pyx", line 159, in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas
\index.c:4018)
  File "pandas\hashtable.pyx", line 675, in pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.g
et_item (pandas\hashtable.c:12368)
  File "pandas\hashtable.pyx", line 683, in pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.g
et_item (pandas\hashtable.c:12322)
KeyError: 'Adju. Close'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\student\Desktop\Coursea\MachineLearning\Sentdex\2.py", line 17,
 in <module>
    df['label'] = df[forecast_col].shift(-forecast_out) #moves columns out 10% i
nto future
  File "C:\Users\student\Anaconda2\envs\py35\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame
.py", line 1997, in __getitem__
    return self._getitem_column(key)
  File "C:\Users\student\Anaconda2\envs\py35\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame
.py", line 2004, in _getitem_column
    return self._get_item_cache(key)
  File "C:\Users\student\Anaconda2\envs\py35\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\gener
ic.py", line 1350, in _get_item_cache
    values = self._data.get(item)
  File "C:\Users\student\Anaconda2\envs\py35\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\inter
nals.py", line 3290, in get
    loc = self.items.get_loc(item)
  File "C:\Users\student\Anaconda2\envs\py35\lib\site-packages\pandas\indexes\ba
se.py", line 1947, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
  File "pandas\index.pyx", line 137, in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas
\index.c:4154)
  File "pandas\index.pyx", line 159, in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas
\index.c:4018)
  File "pandas\hashtable.pyx", line 675, in pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.g
et_item (pandas\hashtable.c:12368)
  File "pandas\hashtable.pyx", line 683, in pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.g
et_item (pandas\hashtable.c:12322)
KeyError: 'Adju. Close'
```

Currently I four python installations. Two environments in anaconda, which all appear to function well and two 'normal' python installations, 2.7 and 3.5. I've tried installing `pandas` multiple times in case it was corrupted but it did nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The traceback references the command:

```
forecast_col = 'Adju. Close'
```

which should probably be `'Adj. Close'` given that's how the `columns` seem to be named.

Comment: What confused me about this operation is, if we have shifted the Adj. Close column to 10 days in the future (I guess just replicating the values of day 1-10 to day 11-20), we don't have the values for ` 'HL_PCT', 'PCT_change', 'Adj. Volume'` for 10 days in the future. If that's the case how is `X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = cross_validation.train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2)
` going to provide corresponding values of `'HL_PCT', 'PCT_change', 'Adj. Volume'` for `label` for 10 days in the future?

where X and y is

```X = np.array(df.drop(['label'], 1))
y = np.array(df['label'])```